# Optimize the query by removing "Union All" for a query with similar conditions

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, union-all

I have the following query in `PHP`:

```
$query = "Select 'NOTE' note_type, u.UserName,n.NoteId id,n.NoteText note,
                n.TimeStamp Time_Stamp,u.UserShortCode,i.IssueId,i.ProjectFile_FileId
                from Note n inner join UserNote un
                on n.NoteId = un.Note_NoteId inner join User u 
                on u.UserId = un.User_UserId
                inner join Issue i on i.IssueId = un.Issue_IssueId
                inner join Issue i2 on i.ProjectFile_FileId = i2.ProjectFile_FileId
                and i2.IssueId = ?

        union all

        SELECT 'AUDIT_NOTE' note_type,u.UserName,a.AuditId id,a.AuditNote note,
            a.AuditTimeStamp Time_Stamp,u.UserShortCode,i.IssueId,i.ProjectFile_FileId
            FROM `eoffice`.`audit` a inner join User u
            on u.UserId = a.User_UserId
            inner join Issue i on i.IssueId = a.Issue_IssueId
            inner join Issue i2 on i.ProjectFile_FileId = i2.ProjectFile_FileId
            and i2.IssueId = ?
            order by Time_Stamp asc;";
```

I wanted to optimize the query by removing the **union all**, thus shortening it.

The following are the necessary table and thier respective fields:

1)*Note*: NoteId,NoteText,TimeStamp

2)*UserNote*: User_UserId, Note_NoteId, Issue_IssueId

3)*User*: UserId, UserName, UserShortCode

4)*Audit*: AuditId, AuditNote, Issue_IssueId, User_UserId, AuditTimeStamp

5)*Issue*: IssueId, ProjectFile_FileId

---

Any Help would by appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: "I wanted to optimize the query by removing the union all, thus shortening it." *optimize* is not the same thing as *shortening*. Are you looking to reduce the "apparent complexity" of the query or do you have some performance issues? In that case, maybe you should provide the execution plan and show how your tables are created, and which index you defined.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux what i actually wanted to do is remove the redundancy in the conditions of the 2 sub-queries.... also by doing that i wanted to check if it optimizes the query...
The table structure u r asking for is specified in the question!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see any clue about which index are defined on your tables. And this is of major interest while talking about "optimization".

Comment: @SylvainLeroux can you please specify what do you mean by the term **`index`** so that i can put it in the question for you...